# Rails how to do distinct and group by query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Lets say I have a table visits with visit_id and created_at and there will be many visits with same visit_id.

Now I want to plot a graph every 10 minutes unique visits. Is it possible to do it in one query? How can I do this in rails?

Before I had unique visits stored in table so I did this

```
 Visit.
   select(:created_at).
   where("DATE(created_at)>=? and DATE(created_at)<=?",from_date,to_date).
   group("ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) / 10)").
   count
```

Ans I got my result. But when there is a need of grouping `visit_id` also I am not able to write the query.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add `visit_id` to group also by visit:

```
Visit.
  select(:created_at).
  where("DATE(created_at)>=? and DATE(created_at)<=?",from_date,to_date).
  group("visit_id, ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) / 10)").
  count
```